# How to make UIView animation re-execute, not .repeat in IOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, animation, random, uiview, repeat

I would like to extend UIView to include an animation that makes a view shake (in consecutive but RANDOM rotations and translation distances) for an indefinite period.

I tried adding the following extention to UIView:

```
func tremble() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        var randomFromZeroToOne = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        let randomBool:Bool = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
        if randomBool { randomFromZeroToOne = -randomFromZeroToOne }
        let degrees = randomFromZeroToOne / 5
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: randomFromZeroToOne, y: randomFromZeroToOne)    
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degrees)       
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

But I am seeing now that the .repeat option simply repeats the exact same animation (with all the initially defined "random" variables, and it does not re-EXECUTE the animation (creating new random variables with each execution).

How can I make it do what I want?  I have tried other options such as .beginFromCurrentState, .overrideInheritedOptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
 func tremble() {

        var randomFromZeroToOne = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        let randomBool:Bool = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
        if randomBool { randomFromZeroToOne = -randomFromZeroToOne }
        let degrees = randomFromZeroToOne / 5

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [ .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: randomFromZeroToOne, y: randomFromZeroToOne)    
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degrees)       
    }, completion: {
        self.tremble()
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks Sh_Khan, I'm working on this... I have to put $0 in the completion to make XCode shut up... and when I say view.layer.removeAllAnimations() ... it still continues.

Comment: @BooberBunz view.layer.removeAllAnimations() works for Core Animations not for UIView Animations. You can take bool variable to check whether your tremble function should execute again or not.